# Capturar un QRCode con la libreria ZXing en Android

Tags: java, android, qrcode

Intento hacer un lector `QRCode` usando la librería [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) pero no encuentro ni las dependencias necesarias para incrustar y un ejemplo básico para empezar.

Quiero solo eso que salga la cámara con la barra roja y devuelve el código QRCode escaneado.

Acabo de encontrar un .jar
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core/3.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenes que ir a tu archivo **"build.gradle"** en la carpeta **"Gradle Scripts"** y en las dependencias agregar :

```
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
```

Te quedaría algo como:

```
dependencies {
    .
    .
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
    .
    .
}
```

Luego le das al botón que te aparece arriba a la derecha "Sync Now"

Eso lo haces para que el Adroid Studio agregue la libreria al proyecto.

Te dejo un codigo simples de como podes obtener el QR en un Activity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class ScannerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);

        IntentIntegrator intent = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        intent.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);

        intent.setPrompt("Scan");
        intent.setCameraId(0);
        intent.setBeepEnabled(false);
        intent.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
        intent.initiateScan();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null){
            if (result.getContents() == null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelaste el escaneo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si ahora justo acabo de encontrar un tutorial https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543668/integrate-zxing-in-android-studio si quieres hacer la transcripción

Comment: Me alegro que hayas resuelto tu problema. Yo justo ahora estoy en una tarea de Android y estoy haciendo cosas con el QR. Solo te pido que indiques mi respuesta como la correcta. Un abrazo

Answer (score 1):

Como complementación a la respuesta del compañero @Casca

**Instalación**
Instalación de la dependencia:

`compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'`

#### Iniciar captura

Para inicializar una captura rápida des de una `Activity`

`new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan();`

Si se usa fragmento

`IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this).initiateScan();`

#### Personalización

Se puede personalizar, como los tipos de códigos a escanear con `setDesiredBarcodeFormats` el texto que se muestra por pantalla `setPrompt` la camará trasera `0` o la delantera `1`

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ONE_D_CODE_TYPES);
integrator.setPrompt("Scan a barcode");
integrator.setCameraId(0);
integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
integrator.initiateScan();
```

#### Leer Resultado

Para interceptar el resultado del escaneo se hace con `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Extraído de: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

#### Más ejemplos

Este repositorio [Proyecto-de-prueba](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/tree/master/sample) se encuentra varios ejemplos de uso

- [AnyOrientationCaptureActivity](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/AnyOrientationCaptureActivity.java)
- [ContinuousCaptureActivity](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java)
- [CustomScannerActivity](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/CustomScannerActivity.java)
- [ToolbarCaptureActivity](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ToolbarCaptureActivity.java)

Comment: no se puede definir para que salga en un recuadro pequeño y no toda la pantalla ?